# Why can I only send plain text e-mails with the communicate tool?

Tags: email, html-email

If I send an HTML e-mail using the communicate tool in the control panel it will be delivered but the body is always blank. I can send plain text e-mails with the communicate tool and the body is received. I'd like to get this resolved so I can send either HTML or plain text using the communicate tool. Any tips or suggestions on correcting this issue would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: This is definitely not expected behaviour. What version of EE are you running? Have you tried a test with very simple HTML?

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for your comments. I'm running EE 2.5.2 on a Red Hat 6.6 Linux server with PHP 5.4.3.7. If I use example 4 from the php.net website (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) the HTML e-mail is delivered perfectly. However, when I try to send just a simple test using the communicate tool with "<h1>Test</h1>" in the body a blank message is received. Therefore the issue must be something to do with EE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was somehow related to the Postfix configuration on the server. Once I changed the default MTA back to Sendmail the issue was resolved!

Answer (score 1):

This could be a spf issue.

I'm currently trying to problem solve the same issue with expressionengine 2.9.3 - html emails are coming through with a blank message, but plain text emails do contain the message.

If I look at the raw source of the email I can see:

```
spf=fail (google.com: domain of sales@xxx.com does not designate aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd as permitted sender)
```

So worth checking your spf record for the domain you are sending this email from with a tool like [mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf:) - i.e. if you are sending the email from **sales@yourdomain.com** check the spf record for **yourdomain.com**

Comment: Thanks anchovy! This might of been related as well so I gave you an up vote. I actually updated our SPF record right around the time this was resolved which makes me wonder if that was the fix entirely or if it was just changing the MTA back to sendmail as I originally thought.